# How to remove footer in second page of TOC without removing the footer in all main pages?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, footer

My problem is having two pages of TOC and on the second page the footer exists, while on the first page there's no footer at all. I've tried adding some code like `\cleardoublepage` and `\pagestyle{plain}` but when I run it, my footer on the main pages is gone.
This is my code:

```
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE. In my experience your type of question is easier to answer with a complete minimal working example of your code, including a (minimal) preamble and the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` markers. Especially since your question is tied to the layout you are using, it is important to know which packages you are using.

Comment: Normally all ToC pages have footers. You need to show what you have done with an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can process. In any event, why do you not want footers on ToC page which is the normal practice in published works?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\pagestyle{empty}` to set the style of `\frontmatter` without footers.

(However, use such a practice with care, see note)

`\tableofcontents` (also `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`) will issue a `\pagestyle{plain}` by default, putting the page number at the bottom.

**Note:** it is recommended not to have two consecutive pages without page numbers. Most editorial houses will not accept such document.

Since there may be other material on the `\frontmatter`, longer the two pages, you should start using normal headings, for example, with your own style.

In two-side books, where the chapter always starts on odd pages, occasionally a blank page may appear before. Just in this case we normally remove all headers and footers including the page number.
[image: b]

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{Author Name\hfill Book Title\hfill}

\begin{document}
    
    \frontmatter
                    
    \tableofcontents
    \pagestyle{empty} % no headings nor footers from here
    
    \kant[1-4]  
    
    \listoffigures

    \kant[1-4]
    
    \listoftables   
    \kant[1]            

    \chapter*{Presentation} % several pages long
    \pagestyle{myheadings} % some headings defined for odd pages
    
    \kant[11-18]
    \mainmatter
    
    \chapter{First}
    
    \kant[11-18]
    
\end{document}
```